# exponential form to normal form in pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm having the following program:

```
var
  N, M, Result: Real;
begin
  Readln(N);
  Readln(M);

  if (N > 0) and (M > 0) then
    Result := N / M;
  
  Writeln(Result:10);
  Readln();
end.
```

and I want the result to be in a normal form, not the exponential form (for example, 8.29 instead of 8.29E+000)

Comment: Which Pascal compiler do you use ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Writeln (Result:10:2);
```

The 2 means "2 decimal places."

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Formatting_output

Answer (score 1):

Use the format specifiers of `Writeln`, like
`Writeln(Result:10:2)`, for 2 decimal digits.

Besides, your result variable will be undefined if N or M are <0. It's better to initialize it, e.g. to 0.

Comment: Ok, thank you!!! And what if the result is too big (for example 9.32E+005) and I want it as a normal number?? That method doesn´t work for big number.... :-/